# ¿Como detener proceso de scheduleTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hilos

Buena tarde!
Estoy trabajando con Executors, tengo un botón que a la hora de presionarlo hace una toast cada 5 segundos, mi pregunta es si hay forma de matar ese proceso al volver a presionar el botón.

lei que con `future.cancel()` pero aun no puedo implementarlo.

El siguiente código es el que muestra el toast cada 5 segundos

```
scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Mensaje cada 5 segundos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias!!

Comment: Debes usar cancel() no shutdown()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes detenerlo usando el método `shutdown()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown()
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo!! me fue de gran ayuda.

Comment: Así matas todos las tareas futuras, no solo las que te interesa parar.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo con el método `cancel()` del un objeto de tipo `ScheduledFuture` tienes que obtener el objeto `ScheduledFuture` que retorna el método `scheduleAtFixedRate()` del objeto `scheduleTaskExecutor`.

```
scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);

// Obtines el objeto de tipo ScheduledFuture que retorna el metodo scheduleAtFixedRate().
ScheduledFuture future = scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Mensaje cada 5 segundos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// finalizas la ejecucion de la tarea.
future.cancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al invocar [scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) te devuelve un [ScheduledFuture](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html). Como todas las implementaciones de `Future`, tiene un método `cancel(boolean)`.

De hecho esto es en general para todos los executors; al enviarles una tarea te devuelve un `Future` que puedes usar para acceder a la tarea y sus resultados.