# Modernizar obtención de valor a retornar con tiempo límite en Java

Tags: java, hilos, java-7, executorservice

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
@RunWith(ParallelRunner.class)
@Parallel(count = AbstractParallelRunnerTest.CONCURRENT_COUNT)
public abstract class AbstractParallelRunnerTest {

.
.
.
private static boolean success(Condition condition)
        throws InterruptedException {
    int timeout = 0;
    while (timeout < 2000) {
        if (condition.isSatisfied()) {
        return true;
        }
        timeout += 50;
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ese código tien el problema de que al llamar al `Thread.sleep` dentro de un ciclo podría causar que duerma más del tiempo necesario.

Para solucionarlo debo de hacer un código que funcione de Java 7 en adelante y pensé en usar executors pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas, pues basado en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122718/como-detener-proceso-de-scheduletaskexecutor/122725#122725) intenté esto:

```
private static boolean success(final Condition condition)
        throws InterruptedException {

    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService
            = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    final Runnable command = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (condition.isSatisfied()) {
                result.set(true);
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        }
    };

    final ScheduledFuture<?> future = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            command, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );


    try {
        future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result.get();
}
```

Sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error

> ```
> com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.PerfTestExecutionError: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.util.ContiPerfUtil.executionError(ContiPerfUtil.java:72)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.JUnitInvoker.invoke(JUnitInvoker.java:56)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.util.InvokerProxy.invoke(InvokerProxy.java:48)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.PerformanceTracker.invoke(PerformanceTracker.java:105)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.CountRunner.run(CountRunner.java:54)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.PerfTestStatement.evaluate(PerfTestStatement.java:79)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.ParallelScheduler$1.call(ParallelScheduler.java:60)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.ParallelScheduler$1.call(ParallelScheduler.java:58)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.success(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:136)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.waitToForceCachedThreadPoolToCreateNewThread(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:97)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.logCurrentThread(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:92)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.shouldRunInParallel5(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:85)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>         at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.JUnitInvoker.invoke(JUnitInvoker.java:53)
>         ... 16 more

Y posteriormente:

> ```
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.success(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:136)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.waitToForceCachedThreadPoolToCreateNewThread(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:97)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.logCurrentThread(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:92)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.shouldRunInParallel1(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:61)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>         at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.JUnitInvoker.invoke(JUnitInvoker.java:53)
>         at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.util.InvokerProxy.invoke(InvokerProxy.java:48)
>         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)   at
>   com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.PerformanceTracker.invoke(PerformanceTracker.java:105)
>
> ```
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.CountRunner.run(CountRunner.java:54)
>   at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.PerfTestStatement.evaluate(PerfTestStatement.java:79) at
> ```
>
> com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.success(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:136)
>         at com.github.javatlacati.contiperf.junit.AbstractParallelRunnerTest.waitToForceCachedThreadPoolToCreateNewThread(AbstractParallelRunnerTest.java:97)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)

¿Cómo puedo corregir mi código?

### Solución

De momento lo tengo así y me funciona en local, pero algunas pruebas relacionadas fallan [en mi integración contínua](https://travis-ci.org/javatlacati/contiperf/builds/625387076), así que no lo pondré como respuesta hasta no verificar que halla una forma menos mañosa de hacerlo

```
private static boolean success(final Condition condition)
        throws InterruptedException {

    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService
            = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    final AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    ScheduledFuture<?> future = null;

    final ScheduledFuture<?> finalFuture = future; //variable for pointer holding
    final Runnable command = new Runnable() {
        private boolean valueSet = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (valueSet) {
                if (finalFuture != null) {
                    finalFuture.cancel(true); // early return
                }
            } else {
                if (condition.isSatisfied()) {
                    result.set(true);
                    valueSet = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    future = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            command, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
    );


    try {
        future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        future.cancel(true);
    }

    return result.get();
}
```

Comment: Qué te hace pensar que con el segundo código no va a dormir más tiempo del necesario?

Comment: que ya le puse un `finalFuture.cancel(true);` en las tres horas que llevo probando

Comment: ¿Quién es `finalFuture`? ¿Dónde llamas al `cancel()`?

Comment: Ya lo puse en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te decía en un comentario, la segunda solución tiene el mismo problema de que se puede estar esperando innecesariamente para comprobar si la condición se cumple.

Con la primera porque siempre que no se cumple pones a dormir el hilo 50 milisegundos y solo una vez transcurridos estos vuelves a comprobar, por lo que si la condición no se cumple al momento de la comprobación pero al pasar 1 milisegundo ya se cumple, estarás esperando 49 milisegundos para preguntar de nuevo.

La segunda solución tiene más de lo mismo. Al usar un `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` indicando un intervalo de 50 milisegundos lo que haces es básicamente el mismo proceso de la solución 1, con un agregado de complejidad y código adicional.

Por tales motivos si fuera yo utilizaría la variante 1, que es más simple, pero de todos modos te pongo ambas variantes. En la primera no te comento mucho ya que no lo considero necesario. En la segundo te pongo las explicaciones en los comentarios del código.

**Variante 1: Ciclo `for`**

```
    private static boolean success(Condition condition) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!condition.isSatisfied() && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 2000) {}

        return condition.isSatisfied();
    }
```

**Variante 2: `ExecutorService`**

```
    private static boolean success(final boolean condition) throws InterruptedException {

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        // Bandera para forzar la detención de la ejecución
        final AtomicBoolean stopCommand = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        final AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        final Runnable command = () -> {
            while (!condition.isSatisfied() && !stopCommand.get()) {}
            result.set(condition.isSatisfied());
        };

        executorService.execute(command);
        // Le indico al ExecutorService que termine una vez finalicen las tareas
        // que actualmente están en ejecución pero que a la vez deje de aceptar
        // nuevas tareas
        executorService.shutdown();

        // Como shutdown() retorna inmediatamente hago esto para forzar a que
        // el hilo actual se bloquee por HASTA 2 segundos, hasta que terminen de
        // ejecutarse las tareas del ExecutorService.
        // Si pasado dicho tiempo las tareas no han finalizado aún retornará false
        // pero permitirá continuar con la ejecución de este método
        executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Hago esto para forzar la finalización de la tarea, ya que puede seguir
        // ejecutándose porque no se ha cumplido la condición
        stopCommand.set(true);

        return result.get();
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa la demora en responderte pero tuve que salir. Cualquier cosa en te pueda ayudar me lo comentas. Saludos.